# Custom view in navigationItem titleView is jumping when view controller is pushed iOS10 only

Tags: ios, swift, navigationbar, uinavigationitem

I'm trying to set a custom `UILabel` my `navigationItem`'s `titleView`. In `viewDidLoad` I have the following code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   let subtopicLabel = UILabel()
   subtopicLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   subtopicLabel.text = subtopicName
   subtopicLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20.0)
   subtopicLabel.textColor = ThemeService.text120
   let width: CGFloat = view.frame.width * 0.7
   subtopicLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width).isActive = true
   subtopicLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
   navigationItem.titleView = subtopicLabel
}
```

This works fine for iOS 11+ however if I push to this view controller in **iOS 10** the label seems to start further up the screen and then jumps down into position. Please see the gif below:

[image]

Any ideas what might be causing this and how I can fix it? Tried moving the code to `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and `viewDidAppear`, no luck though. Any pointers on this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You fixed this?